# Turning on Aerial Faith Plate trajectory display?

Tags: portal-2

In the Advanced Aerial Faith Plate room, the commentary node shows you trajectory lines for the Aerial Faith plates and talks about some of the implementation details of them. I was wondering if all of the trajectory visualization data was still present for the rest of the game and if there was a way to turn them on (presumably via the console)?

Comment: The dev commentary implied it was just a debugging tool, so I'm unsure if they left an accessible version in the game. Would be neat if they did, though!

Comment: I can't imagine that it's inaccessible, all that information is there anyways (though perhaps not rendered for every possible path), 2. using an already developed debugging tool instead of developing one that does the same thing seems like a no brainer, and 3. map makers will certainly want to make use of it when the SDK comes out.

Comment: I did find [this list of Console Commands](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_Command_List).  There's a massive number of commands in there, but if what you're looking for exists, it might be in there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `Steam\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\maps`, you can find the commentary information called `sp_a2_trust_fling_commentary.txt` which contains these two relevant lines:

```
"precommands" "developer 1;ent_bbox trigger_catapult"
"postcommands" "ent_bbox trigger_catapult;developer 0"
```

So, you can run `developer 1` to enable developer commands and `ent_bbox trigger_catapult` to trigger the debugging information for the `trigger_catapult` entity.

Here is what happens when I do `developer 1;ent_bbox trigger_catapult` without triggering:

[image]