# How to enable trajectory lines in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2, portal-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning on Aerial Faith Plate trajectory display?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/turning-on-aerial-faith-plate-trajectory-display)

I want to see the [trajectory lines mentioned in developers commentary (youtube link)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUivczCWTMA#t=33s) in Portal 2; developers used them to debug application. I was able to [enable a console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/how-to-enable-portal-2-developer-console-on-non-us-keyboard-layout).

I apologize but I found answer while typing this. The answer is to type "enable_debug_overlays 1".

Comment: Could someone please add these tags "developers-commentary trajectory debug", they might be handy, only if You want them there, thanks. :)

Comment: Please don't mark your question as "Solved" in the title. Instead, please post the answer as an answer using the Answer field below.

Comment: I edited it. I just found out I can't answer my own questions yet ... after 7-8 hours I can do it. :)

Comment: @lunboks It's useful knowledge, it should just be posted as a self-answer like Grace Note said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `enable_debug_overlays 1` in the console to enable the trajectory lines.